# MongoDB C# driver: how to ignore deserialization errors?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, bson

Most of docs in my collection look like this:

```
{ stuff: "value" }
```

And class is:

```
class Document
{
    public string Stuff { get; set; }
}
```

But occasionally there is a embedded doc instead of string value and the driver fails to deserialize them.

Is there any easy way I can tell the driver to just return default value in that case?

Implementing the whole `IBsonSerializer` seems to be an overkill to me.

Answer (score 0):

You could migrate the data with update and then not worry about the serialization issue:

```
db.things.update(
    { $where : "!Array.isArray(this.stuff)" }, 
    { $set: {stuff: []} }, 
    { multi: true}
);
```